# error with reading SQLite data base with Core Data

Tags: swift, sqlite, core-data, core-data-migration, nspersistentstore

I have middle database which I preload in application, also then I use light weight migration for update this database, but when I have first time called NSPersistentStoreCoordinator I have an error "database disk image is malformed"

for preload database I using following code in my AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path) {
    let sourceSqliteURLs = [Bundle.main.url(forResource: "SingleViewCoreData", withExtension: "sqlite")!, Bundle.main.url(forResource: "SingleViewCoreData", withExtension: "sqlite-wal")!, Bundle.main.url(forResource: "SingleViewCoreData", withExtension: "sqlite-shm")!]
            
    let destSqliteURLs = [self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite"),self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite-wal"),self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite-shm")]
            
    for index in stride(from:0, to: destSqliteURLs.count, by: 1) {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: sourceSqliteURLs[index], to: destSqliteURLs[index])
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

then for light weight migration I use new core data model v 2 and add this code to persistentStoreCoordinator

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    let mOptions = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]
    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: mOptions)
    } catch {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" as AnyObject?
            dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason as AnyObject?

        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        print("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }
        
    return coordinator
}()
```

What am I doing wrong or how to fix this?
Update and install always works when I'm starting app on the device via XCode and doesn't work when I use TestFlight versions...